# Downloading... don't turn off target (S7 Edge)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I accidentally went to download mode and this "downloading don't turn off target message" appeared. It took me at least 20 seconds before I finally pressed volume down + home button + power button. My phone seemed to have rebooted after I did this. Was any harm done? Did my phone download something? Kinda worried because I'm not sure if it damaged my phone or something﻿. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's [Odin mode](https://www.kingoapp.com/help/download-mode.htm), designed for flashing firmwares from PC via Odin or Heimdall. As long as you didn't flash anything during the period, you're fine.